# Datediff between multiple rows for certain ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, range, datediff

My DB Table has a data set with `datetime` values.
How can I return a result set, that returns the `datediff` between the smallest and the highest date only in case the `datediff` between two values are not larger than 5 minutes?

```
Date  
2018-01-01 00:00:00  
2018-01-01 00:01:00  
2018-01-01 00:02:00  
2018-01-01 00:03:00  
2018-01-01 00:04:00  
2018-01-01 00:13:00  
2018-01-01 00:14:00  
2018-01-01 00:15:00  
2018-01-01 00:19:00  
2018-01-01 00:54:00  
2018-01-01 00:59:00  
2018-01-01 01:00:00
```

Result set should look like this:

```
Ranges(min)  
5  
4  
1  
2
```

What would be an approach for that query?

Comment: Please explain how your results (5, 4, 1 and 2) were calculated and from which lines you would get those values. I can't understand at all what those 4 values mean given your current explanations

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: First 5 Values make the first group. Value 5 of the result set is Datediff(n,2018-01-01 00:00:00. 2018-01-01 00:01:00)+1 // The second group makes Datediff + 1 from 2018-01-01 00:13:00 and 2018-01-01 00:19:00 // I need to correct the last two values of the result set (you´re right), since datediff between 2018-01-01 00:54:00 and 2018-01-01 00:59:00 is 5 minutes and so within the range. The last value is Datediff + 1 between 2018-01-01 00:54:00 and 01:00:00

Comment: which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: sql server 2014

Answer (score 1):

You can put breaks in whenever there is a gap of more than 5 minutes.  Then accumulate the number of breaks to define a group and aggregate:

```
select min(dte), max(dte), count(*) as cnt
from (select t.*,
             sum(isbreak) over (order by dte) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when lag(dte) over (order by dte) > dateadd(minute, -5, dte)
                         then 0 else 1
                    end) as isbreak
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by grp;
```

For some reason (not clear to me right now), I thought your question involved SQL Server, so it uses that syntax.  `lag()` is ANSI standard functionality and available in most databases; date arithmetic does vary among databases.